# How to apply Data Validation tool across a row in Excel

Tags: excel

Greetings.

I am looking for a formula that could be used for data validation.
Column A has the value 26226, I do not wish anyone to key in exactly the same value into Column B, within the same row.
Any number works in Column B except for duplicate value.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this not be done with standard data validation, rather than a custom formula? Select the range you wish the validation to apply to, click 'data validation' in the data tab, then in 'settings' allow 'decimal', 'not equal to' and then set value either to 26226 or =$A1. (Be careful how you use absolute values, you might want $A$1 if the validation is to apply to many rows in column B)

Comment: Oh yes it works! Previously I had issues because numbers are stored as text. but yea standard validation works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I made it using custom formula and using =$A1 <> $B1 (you can then drag to the column)